# Example database query failing; can you help me troubleshoot?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to update a Wordpress database table called "dogs_postmeta."
Below is my query, which works perfectly for displaying all appropriate data.

```
select meta_value as field_i_want_to_change, i.url as data
from dogs_postmeta
inner join (select a.post_id, CONCAT('https://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/', b.meta_value) as url
from
dogs_postmeta a, dogs_postmeta b
where
a.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' and
b.post_id = a.meta_value and
b.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
) i
on i.post_id = dogs_postmeta.post_id
where
dogs_postmeta.meta_key = "_seopress_pro_rich_snippets_article_img"
limit 100;
```

I want to update an existing field - meta_value w/the above "data" property. I have been at this for several hours w/o success.

Here's what I've tried.

```
update dogs_postmeta
set dogs_postmeta.meta_value = i.url
from (select a.post_id, CONCAT('https://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/', b.meta_value) as url
from
dogs_postmeta a, dogs_postmeta b
where
a.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' and
b.post_id = a.meta_value and
b.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
) i
inner join dogs_postmeta on dogs_postmeta.post_id = i.post_id 
where
dogs_postmeta.meta_key = "_seopress_pro_rich_snippets_article_img";
```

I get this error message -

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'from (select a.post_id,
>   CONCAT('https://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/', b.meta_va' at line 3

... but I'm sure that's not the issue.

Could anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: Put the `CONCAT` on the same line as `SET dogs....  = CONCAT(....)`.

Comment: I tried earlier. But here's the new error message after doing so - Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'from (select a.post_id, b.meta_value as url from dogs_postmeta a, dogs_postme' at line 3

Comment: I just tried w/o the CONCAT altogether and I still get an error message.

Comment: remove the subquery at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update dogs_postmeta as d
inner join (select a.post_id,  b.meta_value as url
from
dogs_postmeta a, dogs_postmeta b
where
a.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' and
b.post_id = a.meta_value and
b.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
) as i on d.post_id = i.post_id 
set d.meta_value = CONCAT('https://mydomain/wp-content/uploads/', i.url)
where
d.meta_key = "_seopress_pro_rich_snippets_article_img";
```

Comment: Thanks gents, here was my solution. I kept plugging away and changed some formatting to arrive at the above.